# How toScroll automatically in a ScrollView with react native?

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to create a custom DatePicker without using any of the native pickers. using `moment` I've managed to render days months and I've created an array with years between 1900 and current year. Using `pagingEnabled` on each `ScrollView` I've created like picker effect.

Now what I want to do is to scroll to current date from 1/Jan/1900

I've used `onScroll` method in `ref` just for days to test but seem to not work in iOS or Android only Web

https://snack.expo.io/@zoolle/datepicker

Any idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `scrollTo` is not available at the time it is called, most likely because the component has not been fully rendered yet.

You can solve it by adding a small timeout:

```js
ref={scrollView => {
  if (scrollView !== null && this.scrollView !== scrollView) {
    this.scrollView = scrollView;
    setTimeout(() => scrollView.scrollTo({ y: currentDay * 100 }), 100);
  }
}}
```